# getting the real exit code after proc_open

Tags: php, process, pipe, exit-code

I'm using `proc_open` in php to **launch a subprocess** and send data back and forth.

At some point I'd like to **wait for the process** to end and retrieve the **exit code**.

The problem is that if the process has **already finished**, my call to `proc_close` returns -1.  There is apparently much confusion over what `proc_close` does actually return and I haven't found a way to reliably determine the exit code of a process opened with `proc_open`.

I've tried using `proc_get_status`, but it seems to also return -1 when the process has already exited.

---

### Update

I can't get `proc_get_status` to **ever give me a valid exit code**, no matter how or when it is called.  Is it broken completely?.

Comment: Ran into this again today, and ended up finding my own unanswered question while googling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My understanding is that `proc_close` will never give you a legit exit code.

You can only grab the legit exit code the **first time** you run `proc_get_status` **after** the process has ended. Here's a process class that I [stole](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#97329) off the php.net user contributed notes. The answer to your question is in the is_running() method:

```
<?php
class process {

    public $cmd = '';
    private $descriptors = array(
            0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
            1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
            2 => array('pipe', 'w')
        );
    public $pipes = NULL;
    public $desc = '';
    private $strt_tm = 0;
    public $resource = NULL;
    private $exitcode = NULL;

    function __construct($cmd = '', $desc = '')
    {
        $this->cmd = $cmd;
        $this->desc = $desc;

        $this->resource = proc_open($this->cmd, $this->descriptors, $this->pipes, NULL, $_ENV);

        $this->strt_tm = microtime(TRUE);
    }

    public function is_running()
    {
        $status = proc_get_status($this->resource);

        /**
         * proc_get_status will only pull valid exitcode one
         * time after process has ended, so cache the exitcode
         * if the process is finished and $exitcode is uninitialized
         */
        if ($status['running'] === FALSE && $this->exitcode === NULL)
            $this->exitcode = $status['exitcode'];

        return $status['running'];
    }

    public function get_exitcode()
    {
        return $this->exitcode;
    }

    public function get_elapsed()
    {
        return microtime(TRUE) - $this->strt_tm;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I also was getting unexpected results trying to get the return code via `proc_get_status`, until I realized I was getting the return code of the last command I had executed (I was passing a series of commands to `proc_open`, separated by ;).

Once I broke the commands into individual `proc_open` calls, I used the following loop to get the correct return code. Note that normally the code is executing `proc_get_status` twice, and the correct return code is being returned on the second execution. Also, the code below could be dangerous if the process never terminates. I'm just using it as an example:

```
$status = proc_get_status($process);
while ($status["running"]) {
  sleep(1);
  $status = proc_get_status($process);
}
```